# Image shade in same colors as picture - Flutter

Tags: flutter, styles

I've stumbled on a style I do not know how to achieve in flutter.
Basically, I have a settings page where users can see their profile picture.
As seen in the picture below, I'd like to achieve a shade around the image in the same colors as the image. I guess you could call it a bleed?

[image: Notice the shadow around the image.]

Comment: set shadow in container .... container > circularAvatar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

- Add 2 Images in a `Stack`
- Increase the size of the first image
- Then Wrap second image `BackdropFilter` then add some Blur effect

you can play around with the values to get the result that you want

```dart
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      String NetworkImage =
          'https://www.jamsadr.com/images/neutrals/person-donald-900x1080.jpg';
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: new Container(
              child: new Center(
                child: Stack(clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge, children: [
                  Image(
                    image: Image.network(NetworkImage).image,
                    width: 360,
                    height: 360,
    
                  ),
                  BackdropFilter(
                    filter: new ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 15.0, sigmaY: 15.0),
                    child: Image(
                      image: Image.network(NetworkImage).image,
                      width: 350,
                      height: 350,
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: This indeed worked for me. Little problem, the blur goes too far and blurs a bit of some buttons on top. How do I clip it to stay within the stack? None of the bottom elements are blurred, which makes it weird.

Comment: you can play with `sigmaX`,`sigmaY` values to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Sample code]

> sample code

```
Container(
      height: 80,
      width: 80,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
            spreadRadius: 1,
            blurRadius: 7,
            offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
          ),
        ],
      ),

      child: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/cook.png"),
      ),
    )
```